SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 4 Typescript
//  getStaticPaths function
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/products");
  const products = await res.json();
  const paths = products.map((product: { _id: string }) => ({
    params: { productid: product._id },
  }));
  return { paths, fallback: false };
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  try {
    const { params } = context;
    const productid = params?.productid as string;
    
    if (!productid) {
      throw new Error('Invalid product id');
    }
    
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/products/${productid}`);
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch product');
    }
    
    const product: productInterface = await res.json();

    return {
      props: {
        product: product
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching product:', error);
    return {
      notFound: true, 
    };
  }
};
    

this is an error
SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 4 build . Error: Failed to collect page data for /products/[productid]

When you debug, which operation is producing this error?  What is the exact JSON string value it's attempting to deserialize?

thanks for comment..
i want to show dynamic route by productId. so good.  my localhost succesfully get Output. but main issue when i deployed then i notice that from my [produtid].ts route has error.
my exact json:
https://github.com/raihanuldev/json-data-openapi/blob/main/json-data-sample%20for%20stackovrflow

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try to parse the _id to a string
const paths = products.map((product: { _id: string }) => ({
    params: { productid: product._id.toString() },
  }));


no! it's not working. still showed
SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 4
at JSON.parse ()
